# Reqular expression for 11 digit phone number with 09 prefix

Tags: objective-c, regex, phone-number

I am trying to write a regular expression to handle phone number which starts with "0" followed by "9" and 9 digits which can be anything within 0-9.

```
-(BOOL) validateAlphabets: (NSString *)text{      
     NSString *Regex = @"what should be here?!";
     NSPredicate *TestResult = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex];
     return [TestResult evaluateWithObject:text];
}
```

Then I check the input validation by:

```
if (![self validateAlphabets:self.phoneNumber.text]){
      NSLog(@"Invalid");
   }
else{
      NSLog(@"Valid!");
 }
```

Comment: You can start here http://www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this Regex:

```
09[0-9]{9}
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rA3aN4/1)**

You can try to test it in your function itself like this:

```
-(BOOL) validateAlphabets: (NSString *)text{      
     NSString *Regex = @"what should be here?!";
     NSPredicate *TestResult = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", Regex];
     if(TestResult evaluateWithObject: text)
     return true;
     else
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that my input can be either Farsi or english so when it's Farsi it returns No. would you please let me know how I can support something like:  (0|۰)(9|۹)[0-9۰-۹]{9}, example: ۰۹۱۹۸۶۰۱۹۵۰ @Rahul

Comment: would you please let me know how I can support something like: (0|۰)(9|۹)[0-9۰-۹]{9}, example: ۰۹۱۹۸۶۰۱۹۵۰

Answer (score 2):

I would go with

```
(0|۰)(9|۹)(\d|[dummy]){9} //<-- \d being any digit
```

Replace `dummy` with the numbers of the alphabet you want to support

Comment: Give us your input, this *is* what you've asked for @Niloufar

Comment: 09198601950, I will edit the code and please check if my if statement is correct.

Comment: I have seen that but I don't know why it always log Invalid for me!

Comment: When the regex is used in a `NSString` the backslash must be escaped: `@"09\\d{9}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `NSString` method:

```
- (BOOL)validateAlphabets: (NSString *)text {
    NSString *regEx = @"09\\d{9}";
    NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:regEx options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    return range.location != NSNotFound;
}
```